# Unable to code View and Edit actions in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Four models
Restaurant, RestaurantAddresses, RestaurantCuisines and Cuisine.

I am able to display all the restaurants, thsir addresses and they types of thier cuisines through the page View/Restaurants/index.ctp

However, I am unable to code the view and edit actions, following are the codes I am using for both actions :

Edit action (code):

Edit works but it adds two much entries in the Restaurant_Addresses and Cucines table.

public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->Restaurant->id = $id;

```
              $this->loadModel('Cusine');
            $model_cusine_edit_data = $this->Cusine->find('list');
            $this->set('CusineEditList', $model_cusine_edit_data);



    if (!$this->Restaurant->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid Restaurant');
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {              

        $this->Restaurant->save($this->request->data);

            $this->Session->setFlash('The restaurant has been saved');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
    $this->request->data = $this->Restaurant->read();
    }
}
```

View action (code):

the following code only displays restaurant. name information, unable to see street and postal code.

public function view($id = null) {
        $this->Restaurant->id = $id;

```
    if (!$this->Restaurant->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid user');
    }

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid user');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('restaurant', $this->Restaurant->Read());


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would code your methods. I think your main issue in regards to the data not showing up, is the read method only grabs the first models data and does not get associated data... So I would do a Model::find(), instead of a Model::read() with the contain parameter to get the associated data as well.

Don't forget to add 'Containable' to your models $actsAs parameter.

```
public function edit($id=null){
    $this->Restaurant->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Restaurant->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid Restaurant');
    }

     if(!empty($this->request->data)){
          if($this->Restaurant->save($this->request->data)){
              $this->Session->setFlash('The restaurant has been saved');
              $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
          } else {
              $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to save the restaurant');
          }
     }


     $model_cusine_edit_data = $this->Restaurant->RestaurantCusine->Cusine->find('list');
     $this->set('CusineEditList', $model_cusine_edit_data);

     $this->request->data = $this->Restaurant->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Restaurant.id'=>$id), 'contain'=>array('RestaurantAddresses','RestaurantCusine')));
}

public function view($id=null){
    $this->Restaurant->id = $id;

    if (!$this->Restaurant->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid user');
    }

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid user');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    $this->set('restaurant', $this->Restaurant->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Restaurant.id'=>$id), 'contain'=>array('RestaurantAddresses','RestaurantCusine'))));
}
```

Comment: It's probably more desirable to just add Containable and set recursive to -1 AppModel.

Comment: I am still unable to pull data from other models:

Comment: one of the view.ctp code line is echo $restaurant['Cusine'] ['name']

Answer (score 0):

For the View you need to do a `find('first', array('conditions' => array('Restaurant.id' => $id), 'recursive' => 2));` or, a better way, use the `ContainableBehavior` which lets you choose exactly which models to fetch. Search the book for the usage and example.

As for the edit, provide a link to the post data looks like.